# Before Update Triggers with comparing :old_values and :New_Values unable to update the table column with datatype as TIMESTAMP with SYSDATE VALUE

Tags: oracle10g

```
create or replace TRIGGER "LRMC_ADMIN".LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY_UPDATE_TRIG
BEFORE UPDATE ON LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ORD_STATUS='PND' AND 
    (:NEW.ORD_STATUS='BKD' OR :NEW.ORD_STATUS='CLO') 
  THEN
    :NEW.ORD_MOD_DATE:=SYSDATE;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
    -20500,
    'ERROR IN LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY_UPDATE_TRIG :WHEN TRIGGER TRYING TO UPDATE LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY '||
       sqlerrm);
END;
```

After writing this trigger, I am unable to modify or update column with timestamp as datatype with value as SYSDATE. I want to know the reason and solution for this.

Comment: Here after writing this trigger i am unable to modify or update  column with timestamp as datatype with value as SYSDATE. i want to know the reason and solution for this

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question, and explain what is actually happening. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am explaning the entire secnarion here

Comment: @user1960957 Is your if condition  return true or false?

Comment: @user1960957: no, you're not. "unable to update" isn't precise enough. What does it mean exactly? Does nothing happen? Is the trigger called at all? Is it raising an error?

Comment: @user1960957 You could do a simple statement to check whether any rows are returned `select * from LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY where ORD_STATUS='PND' AND  (ORD_STATUS='BKD' OR ORD_STATUS='CLO')`

Comment: I am explaning the entire senario here 
1> Here i am firing Before Update on trigger on "LRMC_ORDER_ENTRY" table
2> There is a column ORD_MOD_DATE with Timestamp as datatype
3> This trigger compile successfully and works fine

Comment: 4> But now If i Fire this Query"update lrmc_order_entry set ORD_MOD_DATE=SYSDATE where ord_num='IN4329/2012/000001'
"  It should modify the column ORD_MOD_DATE with SYSDATE which is not happening
5> but by disabling this trigger or by removal of ":OLD.ORD_STATUS='PND'" This statemnent it works fine i want to know if by refereing this :OLD variable what kind of promblem i am facing that it makes me ub=nable to run this query "update lrmc_order_entry set ORD_MOD_DATE=SYSDATE where ord_num='IN4329/2012/000001'
"

Comment: Here promblem is when you fire "update lrmc_order_entry set ORD_MOD_DATE=SYSDATE where ord_num='IN4329/2012/000001' " it is not updating theis column ORD_MOD_DATE with SYSDATE i dont know why this is happing?  BUt by disabling above trigger this query works fine

Comment: @user1960957 Do a `select * from lrmc_order_entry where ord_num='IN4329/2012/000001'`

Comment: You've already been asked to update the question, please don't put so much information in comments where it's hard to follow. You still haven't said what actually happens - when you run your `update`, what error do you get? What are the values in the row you're updating?

Comment: Alex i dont get any error only promblem i am facing is that after firing "update lrmc_order_entry set ORD_MOD_DATE=SYSDATE where ord_num='IN4329/2012/000001' "  i am Expecting to to get modified ORD_MOD_DATE to SYSDATE which is not happining

Comment: Polppan i have done this it return me unmodified ORD_MOD_DATE for thatsrow